# Finding the "centered average" of a list

Tags: python, algorithm

"Return the "centered" average of a list of integers, which we'll say is the mean average of the values, except ignoring the largest and smallest values in the list. If there are multiple copies of the smallest value, ignore just one copy, and likewise for the largest value. Use integer division to produce the final average. You may assume that the list is length 3 or more."

This is a problem I have from my homework assignment and I am stumped at how to find the the largest/smallest numbers and cut them out of the list. Here is what I have so far. and It works for 10/14 the scenarios that I have to pass.. I think it is just because it grabs the median

```
def centered_average(nums):
x = 0
for i in range(len(nums)):
    x = i + 0
y = x + 1
if y%2 == 0:
    return (nums[y/2] + nums[(y/2)+1]) / 2
else:
    return nums[y/2]
```

Comment: you can do `max()` and `min()` if they are in a list

Comment: Yup, that code's taking a median. The `y` calculation is bizarre - it's just calculating `len(nums)` - but once you have `y`, that's definitely a median.

Comment: LOL, I can understand that is it weird now that I am looking at it, I am pretty new so I find myself doing weird crap like that all the time and seeing if it works xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorting the array is certainly terser code, here's an alternative with a manual loop

```
    max_value = nums[0]
    min_value = nums[0]
    sum = 0
    for x in nums:
        max_value = max(max_value, x)
        min_value = min(min_value, x)
        sum += x

    return (sum - max_value - min_value) / (len(nums) - 2)
```

This just adds everything in and removes the max and min at the end.

Comment: This is better than sorting.  Your solution is O(n), while sorting would be O(n log n).

Comment: I think the for loop is optional. You could also do it this way: int((sum(input)-max(input)-min(input))/(len(input)-2)).

Comment: @Stanleyrr That will run through `nums` 3 times (since `sum`, `min`, and `max` all have loops under the covers).

Answer (score 1):

If the list isn't too long, it shouldn't be too computationally expensive to sort the list:

```
sorted(nums)
```

Then you can create a new list without the first and last entries, which will be the smallest and largest values:

```
new_nums = sorted(nums)[1:-1] # from index 1 to the next-to-last entry
```

Answer (score 1):

Before i start i know there are easier ways mentioned in the other answers using the function sort, yes that is true but i believe your teacher must have iven you this to able to master loops and use them logically.

First pick your first number and assign it to high and low, don't worry it will make sense afterwards.

def centered average(nums):

```
high = nums[0]
small = nums[0]
```

Here is were the magic happens, you loop through your list and if the number your on in the loop is larger then the previous ones then you can replace the variable high with it, let me demonstrate.

```
for count in nums:
    if count > high:
        high = count
    if count < low:
        low = count
```

Now you have the low and the high all you do is add the values of the loop together minus the high and the low (as you said you do not need them).Then divide that answer by len of nums.

```
for count in nums:
    sum = count + sum
sum = sum - (high + low)
return sum
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I definitely would like to understand everything completely before I go in using short cuts!

Comment: This is good, but you can do better by doing it all in one loop and subtracting out high & low at the end. Don't forget to reduce the len of nums by 2.

Comment: @DaveGalvin I dont think i would need to reduce the length by 2 as I subtracted them out. If i were to reduce the len then i would miss out on 2 other elements. However doing it in one loop is more efficient but I wanted to explain it to OP in separated steps as i find it the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

New here. I like to check my solutions with solutions found on the internet and did not see my code here yet (hence the post). I found this challenge on https://codingbat.com/prob/p126968. And here is my solution:
** This is done in Python 3.9.1.

First the min and max are popped from the list with the index method. After it's just a simple avg calculation.

```
def centered_average(nums):

  nums.pop(nums.index(max(nums)))
  nums.pop(nums.index(min(nums)))
  
  return sum(nums)/len(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, this should work:

```
def centered_average(nums):
  trim = sorted(nums)[1:-1]
  return sum(trim) / len(trim)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def centered_average(nums):
  nums = sorted(nums)
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if len(nums)%2 != 0:
      return nums[len(nums)/2]
    else:
      return ((nums[len(nums)/2] + nums[len(nums)/2 - 1]) / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very sub standard solution to the problem. This code is a bad code that does not take into account any consideration for complexity and space. But I think the thought process to be followed is similar to the steps in the code. This then can be refined.

```
def centered_average(nums):
#Find max and min value from the original list
max_value = max(nums)
min_value = min(nums)
#counters for counting the number of duplicates of max and min values.
mx = 0
mn = 0
sum = 0
#New list to hold items on which we can calculate the avg
new_nums = []
#Find duplicates of max and min values
for num in nums:
  if num == max_value:
    mx += 1
  if num == min_value:
    mn += 1
#Append max and min values only once in the new list
if mx > 1:
  new_nums.append(max_value)
if mn > 1:
  new_nums.append(min_value)
#Append all other numbers in the original to new list
for num in nums:
  if num != max_value and num != min_value:
    new_nums.append(num)
#Calculate the sum of all items in the list
for new in new_nums:
  sum += new
#Calculate the average value.
avg = sum/len(new_nums)

return avg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def centered_average(nums):
  min1=nums[0]
  max1=nums[0]
  for item in nums:
    if item > max1:
        max1 = item
    if item < min1:
        min1 = item
  sum1=(sum(nums)-(min1+max1))/(len(nums)-2)
  return sum1
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

```
def centered_average(nums):
  b=nums

  ma=max(b)
  mi=min(b)

  l=(len(b)-2)

  s=sum(b)-(ma+mi)  
  av=int(s/l)
  return av
```

Answer (score 0):

- use sum function to sum the array
- max and min functions to get the biggest and smallest number

  ```
  def centered_average(nums):
      return (sum(nums) - max(nums) - min(nums)) / (len(nums) - 2)
  ```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def centered_average(nums):
    sorted_list = sorted(nums)
    return sum(sorted_list[1:-1])/(len(nums)-2)
```

This will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 Solution using list.index, list.pop, min and max functions.

```
def solution(input):

    average = 0

    minimum = min(input)
    maximum = max(input)

    input.pop(input.index(minimum))
    input.pop(input.index(maximum))

    average =  round(sum(input) / len(input))

    return average
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def centered_average(nums):
    nums.remove((min(nums)))
    nums.remove((max(nums)))
    new_nums=nums
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(new_nums)):
        count+=1
    ans=sum(new_nums)//count
    return ans
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def centered_average(nums):
    maximums = []
    minimums = []
    sum_of_numbers = 0
    length =len(nums) + (len(minimums)-1) + (len(maximums)-1)
    for i in nums:
        if i == max(nums):
            maximums.append(i)
        elif i == min(nums):
            minimums.append(i)
        else:
            sum_of_numbers += i
    if len(maximums)>=2 or len(minimums)>=2:
        sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + (max(nums)*(len(maximums)-1))(min(nums)*(len(minimums)-1))
    return sum_of_numbers / length
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!